# Can I force row headers to show on an Access crosstab with dynamic column headers?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have tblOuts that tracks Skus out of inventory by Category and date:

| OutDate | Category | Sku |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20210322 | A | 111 |
| 20210322 | B | 222 |
| 20210323 | A | 111 |
| 20210323 | B | 222 |
| 20210323 | B | 333 |
| 20210324 | D | 444 |

I created a crosstab that will show the count of Skus by Category and OutDate:

| Category | 20210322 | 20210323 | 20210324 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 |  |
| B | 1 | 2 |  |
| D |  |  | 1 |

**How can I modify the crosstab to also show Category C, even though it doesn't have any data in my table yet?**

| Category | 20210322 | 20210323 | 20210324 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 |  |
| B | 1 | 2 |  |
| C |  |  |  |
| D |  |  | 1 |

Normally I would create a separate table that listed all Categories and left join it to the crosstab.  But I can't think of an ideal way to do so.

```
SELECT tblCategories.Category, qryCrosstab.*
FROM tblCategories LEFT JOIN qryCrosstab ON tblCategories.Category = qryCrosstab.Category
```

gives me two Category fields, which I don't want:

| tblCategories.Category | qryCrosstab.Category | 20210322 | 20210323 | 20210324 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Alternately, I could do the following, but would need to modify my query every time a new date is added to the table:

```
SELECT tblCategories.Category, qryCrosstab.20210322, qryCrosstab.20210323, qryCrosstab.20210324
FROM tblCategories LEFT JOIN qryCrosstab ON tblCategories.Category = qryCrosstab.Category
```

Comment: _Or can I?_ Yes, you should be able to do so. Try.

Comment: @Gustav, sorry I should have asked that differently.  I can think of two ways to do this with a Left Join.  The first is "SELECT tblCategories.Category, qryCrosstab.*", but that gives me two Category fields.  The second is to update my join query each time a new date is added ("SELECT tblCategories.Category, qryCrosstab.20210322...", but that is less than ideal.  Is there a better way to do the join query?

Comment: The "primary" table table should be the Category table with a left join to the crosstab query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I see what you mean by "doubled":

```sql
SELECT 
    Category.Category, 
    qOut.*
FROM 
    Category 
LEFT JOIN 
    qOut ON Category.Category = qOut.Category;
```

[image]

Can't you just ignore one of those category fields?

Comment: Yes, that's definitely an option if no better solution exists, thank you.  I was just hoping for something without doubled categories, if that's possible.

Comment: The only method I can think of, is to read the field names from the crosstab and then, by code, adjust the SQL of the final query. Certainly doable, and quite common for a query driving a report.

Comment: Thanks.  Just found out that this data is getting fed into Excel, so they're OK ignoring the extra column.  Sorry for the delay in closing this - I was waiting for feedback but the meeting kept getting pushed back.